# Can you use textmate scopes/semantic tokens to restrict usage of snippets in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Okay. This idea might sound crazy but bear with me.

I was writing some snippets for myself earlier and realized how restrictive the "conditional" aspect of the snippets is. The only way to seemingly change anything about the snippet conditionally is through regex, but that doesn't really apply to what I'm thinking about. However, I was thinking that maybe it would be possible to take advantage of the TextMate and Semantic tokens from the syntax highlighting and use them to restrict when/where a snippet can be used so it's not taking up space in your suggestions.

Basically, imagine a VS Code version of adding directives to an AHK script.

Am I wrong about how TextMate/Semantic tokens can affect things or is this actually possible by just making an extension? I'm not too familiar with the vscode APIs so I could be very wrong about all of this.